# Clear Console Buffer

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I'm writing a sample console application in VS2008. Now I have a `Console.WriteLine()` method which displays output on the screen and then there is `Console.ReadKey()` which waits for the user to end the application.

If I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> while the `Console.WriteLine()` method is displaying then the application exits.

How can I clear the input buffer before the `Console.ReadKey()` method so that no matter how many times the user presses the Enter button while the data is being displayed, the `Console.ReadKey()` method should stop the application from exiting?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no built-in method in Console class. But you can do this:

```
while(Console.KeyAvailable) 
    Console.ReadKey(false); // skips previous input chars

Console.ReadKey(); // reads a char
```

Use `Console.ReadKey(true)` if you don't want to print skipped chars.

**Microsoft References**

- [Console.KeyAvailable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.keyavailable?view=net-5.0#System_Console_KeyAvailable)
- [Console.ReadKey(bool)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readkey?view=net-5.0#System_Console_ReadKey_System_Boolean_)

Comment: You da man!  At the last second I noticed that if people banged on the keyboard they could slip through one of my pauses, the above did the trick.  Thanks.