# Console application "remembering" my input before calling ReadKey?

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I have a console application which stores my input when calling `ReadKey()` before that line executes:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Beginning long pause...");
    Thread.Sleep(6000);
    var input = Console.ReadKey();

    Console.WriteLine("You pressed: " + input.Key.ToString());
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

* Small note: You'll need to add `using System.Threading;`.

Now, set a breakpoint on `var input = Console.ReadKey();`. Run the application and immediately press any key. After a few seconds, the breakpoint will trigger. Continue, and the application will print out the key you pressed **before** the breakpoint triggered.

How / why does this happen, and how can I make it so my application won't "remember" any input until `ReadKey()` *actually* executes?

Comment: The keystroke waits in the input buffer until you read it. You might try [discarding everything in the buffer immediately after Sleep, like in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3769828/424129).

Comment: But bear in mind that users like to be able to type ahead, even if the program is currently busy. it can be annoying for a program to throw away my type ahead, so I then have to enter it again.

Comment: @Polyfun It's my own personal utility to make dev work a little easier, so that's not too much of a concern