# How to get rid of the ReadKey() que if a person where to spam a key?

Tags: c#, console, readkey

My console application uses ReadKeys thruout the code; if a person where to say click a key when an ReadKey is not active, it would to my speculation be added to a que of sorts, so when the code gets to the readKey it instantly goes on the previus keypress and continues as if that key was pressed.
Is there a way to fix this?

Edit: To clarify, axidental keypresses affect the ReadKeys that have not yet been run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if there is any key available in the input stream and then read the next key.

A very good solution can be found here: [Clear Console Buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769770/clear-console-buffer)

Another similar solution here: https://newbedev.com/csharp-c-console-clear-input-buffer-code-example

```
// while there are characters in the input stream 
while(Console.KeyAvailable) 
{
    // read them and ignore them
    Console.ReadKey(false); // true = hide input
}
// Now read properly the next available character
Console.ReadKey();
```